# How do you display translated strings using i18next on js alerts?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, i18next

We're developing an app that utilizes html/css/js, and it uses [i18next](http://i18next.com/) to display translated strings.

In order to display translations, I embed an attribute within a tag. For example:

```
<a href="#top" id="agreement" data-i18n="text_agreement">利用規約</a><label for="checkbox2" data-i18n="text_agree">に同意する</label>
```

In addition to this, the app uses a javascript file to replace strings with translations. For instance, the above code corresponds with:

```
en: { translation: {
text_agreement: 'Agree to EULA'
} }
```

This method of translation works for HTML tags. What I don't know is how to translate strings within js code. For instance, how would I display translated strings for this?

```
element.alert('なまえを記入してください。');
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The initialization function gives you a function to translate your strings. ;)

You can 'put' this function to the window object, so you can use it everywhere in your code.

```
i18n.init(function(t) { 
  window.t = t("Your string here");
});
// ... more code
// Now you can use window.t to translate
element.alert(window.t('Your string'));
```

But note that it's asynchronous (!), so it could happen that the console says, that `t()` is undefined.

So first initialize i18next and then use `window.t();`

Also have a look at the documentation: http://jamuhl.github.io/i18next/pages/doc_init.html